# Bash script, running a script from a different directory which internally calls another script?

Tags: python, bash, shell

I am writing a bash script that will execute several scripts for me without me having to stop in between to change directories. I've figured out how to call scripts in different directories but I am having a problem where one script (a.py) internally calls another script (b.py).

Normally, both a.py and b.py are in the same folder and simply running:

```
python a.py
```

This works fine as a.py executes and finds b.py within its own directory and the output works. But it does not work when I execute a bash script.
EDIT: This is the full script so far:

```
#! /usr/bin/bash -x
mkdir $2
python ..\\get_coordinates.py

cd $2
python ..\\get_filenames.py
var1=$(find *.fa)

python ..\\a.py $var1 # Does something to files in var
```

What I run in cmd is:

```
>my_script.sh "coord1,coord2,coord3..." folderA
```

Everything works fine up until calling a.py which seems to not find b.py.
I am not sure why it cannot find b.py when it is there with a.py?

Edit: Here is the error that I do get once I get to a.py.

```
python: can't open file 'b.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
Count not run command:
python b.py --output name.fasta name.fa
find: ‘*.fasta’: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Are you getting some kind of error? `ImportError` maybe?

Comment: Ah yes I am. I will update my main question with the error.

Answer (score 0):

this is what your `PYTHONPATH` environmental variable is for

```
CD NewDir
PYTHONPATH=/dir/of/second_script;/dir/of/first_script python /dir/of/first_script/first.py
```

Comment: But I don't want to go back to the first directory, I need a.py and b.py to execute while in the NewDir so that it can work on the properly identified files that were moved to that new directory.

Comment: Okay I am confused, I never worked with PYTHONPATH. So before I execute python a.py in my bash script, I write the pythonpath lines with the full directory name? Not just pythonpath = ..\\a.py;..\\b.py then call python on a.py?

Comment: @DNAngel If you know `$PATH` variable, `$PYTHONPATH` is not so different. You just have to put the `directory paths` separated by semicolons. Any python `import` commands will search the python module to be imported in the directories listed in `$PYTHONPATH` as well.

Comment: Thank you, that made more sense. I understand paths but I've always just been confused on how their syntax works (is it "\" or "\\" or "/" etc.) which is why I generally find those hard to follow.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is with your `PYTHONPATH`. What you can do is add these lines to the `a.py` file (at the start of the file)

```
import os
import sys
runnig_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
sys.path.insert(0, runnig_dir)
```

This will add the directory of `a.py` to the `PYTHONPATH`, and then running `b.py` from anywhere should work fine.

Comment: I tried that, I get the same error. Says it can't open file "b.py": [Errno 2] no such file or directory

Comment: Did you mean those lines should be added to b.py since I only need to call a.py (which is a wrapper script that calls b.py).

Answer (score 0):

Okay I missed something very obvious here. Since I had help in creating the main scripts (a.py and b.py) I realized there was an argument parser deep within b.py that allows me to include an argument that calls b.py

So within my bash script, I changed the line to:

```
python ..\\a.py -p ..\\b.py $var
```

And now it works. But, if anyone can still help me figure out a way to call b.py if argumentparsers were not used, that would be helpful as well!